# codename one open app with a button

Tags: button, codenameone

I am confused on how use the buttons. I open the theme designer and create the button, then on the commands i choose the action execute and go to the Source (saving before)

On the code I have this method, on the simulator do nothing and in the device neither (on the simulator start an Open file window, i am using w7)

```
 @Override
protected boolean onMainCommand105() {

    try {
        Display.getInstance().execute("fb://profile/14846274855890");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.show("Error!", "Failed to start.  installed?", "OK", null);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw my mistake thanks to this CN1 tutorial

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html

I should use Action Event, not execute

```
@Override
protected void onMain_Button1Action(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
     try {
        Display.getInstance().execute("https://www.facebook.com/CatedralAltaPatagonia/?fref=ts");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.show("Error!", "Failed to start.  installed?", "OK", null);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or easier :

```
button.addActionListener(l -> {

    System.out.println("test");          

});
```